# How CSS border Radius for text

Tags: css

I want to get like this boarder radius and background color. I tried much time to style like this, please can you guide me how to style like this, text are Create Document and Create Docx

[image]

Comment: "_I tried much time to style like this_" When asking such questions, please include what you already tried and explain what specifically went wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use border-radius, something like this:

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  color: #575d63;
}
```

```html
<span class="button">Create Document</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Show styles absolutes unity and relative

Here an example Approximate measurement

```
unity   Meaning Approximate 
in   Inches  1in = 25.4mm
cm  Centimeters 1cm = 10mm
pc  Spades 1pc = 4.23mm
mm  Millimeters 1mm = 1mm
pt  Points  1pt = 0.35mm
px  Pixels 1px = 0.26mm
Q   Quarter mm  1Q = 0.248mm
```

Relative Units

```
unity   Meaning Approximate 
em  «M» 1em 
ex  «X» (~0.5em)    1ex 
ch  «zero width»    1ch 
rem «root M»    1rem 
%
```

then here apply converting relative to absolutes and absolutes to relative is easy

```
.button {
  border-radius: 2.50em;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 0.7500em 1.2500em;
  color: #575d63;
}
```

[image]